# Encoded values to plain text in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I have encoded values in the table, and wanted to select them as a plain text without altering the database property,

I have tried many ways, but not getting exact result.

Value - `Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł`
Expected - `Er treangt keinen Mantel`

```
SELECT 'Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł', 'Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł'::bytea;
SELECT 'Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł', convert_to('Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł', 'utf-8');
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Those are both "plain text" as far as I can see. Do you mean you want the character-set reduced to ASCII? And if so what is the source character-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) function of the `unaccent` extension.
First create the extension (if not there already). It is included in the EDB installation package.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

and then remove the diacritics

```sql
SELECT
  'Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł' as accented, 
  unaccent('Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł') as unaccented;
```

| accented | unaccented |
| --- | --- |
| Er tręäńgt keinen Manteł | Er treangt keinen Mantel |

I assume that the original character set is UTF8.

Comment: This one works perfectly

Comment: Is there a similar function for Redshift, will be raising a new question. Expecting your inputs for Redshift as well

Comment: I am not familiar with Redshift, sorry.